# How can I create a switchable filter in Pure Data?

Tags: sound, daw, sound-design

I have watched a tutorial series on Pure Data, but I still feel uncertain about how to think about the "execution point" in a Pure Data patch evolving over time.

Suppose I want to create a radio button with which the user can control which filter an audio signal gets passed through.  Something like this, conceptually (the red lines are connections I want to make, but are invalid)...

[image]

The problem is that I cannot pass the audio signal through the Hradio control because the variable typings are incorrect.  I have tried some setups with Moses and Spigot, but I have not been able to figure out how to pass the audio signal through a conditional check in this way.

How can I set this patch up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try this>...

For a Hradio to work you need to have a trigger float bang then you need it to go into sel 0 1 2 to send each individual slide into your source signal. For example I have a signal slider and then inside my pd sine patch I have my oscillator. Depending on how many signals you hve you just have to copy and paste but change your osc~ to another sound if you want, Not sure if this makes sense. But i hope the pictures help

[image]